# Ctags as library for Creating Tag Files

Tags: c, gcc, exuberant-ctags

I need to use Ctags for generating Tag Files but I prefer it as a library not as executable.
Is there any package available already as library?  I have a compiled version with executable but would not like to run new processes in my application.
Any advice or pointer is appreciated

Comment: You get get the source for Exuberant Ctags at http://ctags.sourceforge.net/.  You should be able to use that if you satisfy the GNU GPL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found none, so I have to roll my own!

Comment: I vote for delete because I found a library is for reading tags no creating them. Updated the question!